How to give Selenium Grid a specific firefox profile
I have a Selenium test application which should test a application with a microsoft authentification what I did was use a firefox profile which is on the base level folder structure of my application projekt. So far it works when I start the tests locally with my local driver.
But Now i want the tests to run in selenium grid run by docker but it does not get my profile. How can i tell selenium grid to get my profile and also use it?
This is how it looks in my docker compose.yml:
  selenium:     image: selenium/standalone-firefox     container_name: selenium_firefox     ports:       - "4444:4444"  # Port für WebDriver-Zugriff     volumes:       - "./qmpzwcn5.Selenium-Hasan:/home/seluser/firefox-profile/qmpzwcn5.Selenium-Hasan"     environment:       - GRID_PASSWORD=test123       - SE_VNC_NO_PASSWORD=1       - OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT=http://otel-collector:4317  # Hier die OTEL_ENDPOINT-Variable für Selenium setzen     networks:       - my-network    otel-collector:     image: otel/opentelemetry-collector:latest     ports:       - "4317:4317"  # Exporting the OTLP endpoint     volumes:       - ./otel_config.yaml:/etc/otel/otel_config.yaml     command: ["--config=/etc/otel/otel_config.yaml"]     networks:       - my-network  networks:   my-network:     driver: bridge  volumes:   mysql-data:

Here is my java spring boot:
public WebDriver initializeDriver() {   FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();      // Specify the exact profile path inside the container  FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile(new File("home/seluser/firefox-profile/qmpzwcn5.Selenium-Hasan"));   firefoxProfile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);    firefoxProfile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);  options.setProfile(firefoxProfile);     options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);   try {       URL seleniumRemoteUrl = new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub");        return new RemoteWebDriver(seleniumRemoteUrl, options);     } catch (Exception e) {         e.printStackTrace();        throw new RuntimeException("Fehler beim Initialisieren des RemoteWebDrivers", e);   } }

The funny thing is when I do a docker exec into my container my profile is there as a folder but selenium grid does not show any profiles.
PS: sorry the formatting for some reason did not work...
